# trying to print chars but still prints string

Tags: java, string, char

Im trying to print chars from a 2d char array however i keep getting  back a string instead of each letter. e.g. argument in command line is

"-encrypt abcdefghij"

```
    String command = args[0]; 
    String Text = args[1]; //letters to be 

    char letters [] = Text.toCharArray(); 
    int m = Text.length(); //number of letters to be decrypted/encrypted


    String command = args[0]; 
    String Text = args[1]; //leters to be 

    char letters [] = Text.toCharArray(); 
    int m = Text.length(); //number of letters to be decrypted/encrypted


    if (command.equals("-encrypt")) {

        //if statement was here before for perfect square numbers

        else if     ( m / (int) Math.sqrt(m) != Math.sqrt(m) ) { //non perfect square digits

        int RootM = (int) Math.pow((Math.sqrt(m))+1,2); //overall size of 2d array (depth*width)
        int RootN1 = (int) Math.sqrt(RootM); //length of rows & columns

        char [][] box = new char [RootN1][RootN1]; //define dimensions of 2d array

            for (int i=0; i<RootN1; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<RootN1; j++) {
                    box[i][j]=letters[2*i+j];
                }
            }

            for (int i=0; i<RootN1; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<RootN1; j++) {  

            System.out.print(box[j][i]);
```

Comment: box is a 2D array but you use it as a 1D array when assigning and printing. Maybe that leads to confusion?

Comment: im trying to use the chars to fill in the 2d array but i keep getting output abcd not a,b,c,d

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i=0; i<RootM; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<RootM; j++) {
      box [i] = letters;
      box [j] = letters;
      System.out.print(box[i]); //displays encrypted text
    }
 }
```

is problematic. You put `box[i] = letters` inside the inner loop, therefore it will be executed `RootM*RootM` times, this is the same for the `print` statement. Your may need to clear your assignment and print logic on the `box` 2D char array.

According to your reply to comments, you need to put abcd into `2*2` matrix with first row contains `ab` and second row contains `cd`. You can find the index mapping as follows :

```
index in 1D array:
    0    1    2  3

index in 2D array:

  (0,0) (0,1) (1,0) (1,1)
```

so mapping is:

```
box[i][j] = letters[2*i+j];
```

Now assume that you have a 4*4 matrix:

```
index in 1D array:
0  1  2  3  4 5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15

index in 2D array:
(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,2) ....
```

You will need mapping

```
box[i][j] = letters[4*i+j];
```

In short, if number of rows is N, you need

```
box[i][j] = letters[N*i + j];
```

Your loop should look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<RootM; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<RootM; j++) {
    box [i][j] = letters[2*i+j];
  }
}

//you can now print column by column
for (int i=0; i<RootM; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<RootM; j++) {
     System.out.print(box [j][i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: also do you know how to change the string text into char where so that it prints acbd?

Comment: if the array was filled row by row i.e row 1 contains |a|b| AND row 2 contains |c|d|

Comment: what do you mean by mapping? im a newbie to this java stuff :/

Comment: uh one problem i get the output "abcd" \n "a bd" how come the c is cancelled out?

Comment: for (int i=0; i<RootN1; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j<RootN1; j++) {
      box[i][j]=letters[2*i+j];
    System.out.print(box[j][i]);

Comment: im trying to print column by column hence in the print line i have box[j][i]

Comment: also for longer arguments of 10 characters long, there are 2 spaces in between some of the characters, do yu know why this occurs?

Comment: one more thing why did you do 2*i+j why the number 2?

Comment: @user2269083 you used print, there is not space inserted. so you need to trace back in your own code. I cannot guess the cause. The number 2 is coming from the mapping I have shown in the post. Check how 2*i+j from the "index in 2D array" to "index in 1D array".

Comment: im getting there slowly, thank you again so much for your help :) really appreciate it

Comment: thats weird i fixed the spacing part, but now it prints abcd and on another line it shows acbd

Comment: @user2269083 update your question by replacing your most recent with your the current version?

Comment: yup, i just didnt copy them to the blog because it wastes space

Comment: @user2269083 Is the total output of your program likes: abcd, acbd, not just output from the for loop? since you have another print statement: System.out.println(letters); before the if block. That's why>....

Comment: also, if i tried "abdcefghij" it gives "acegbdfhcegidfhj" something is definitely wrong here :(

Comment: damn, silly, silly me. i forgot to remove println because i was testing which part of my method didn't work

Comment: sorry i didnt copy my "non perfect square" else if statement. please refer to my edited version again.

Comment: @user2269083 I did not see any updates..... Try to remove your earllier comments, this is way too long and system suggests moving to chat, which you don't have enough rep. to do that for now.

Comment: still trying to update it, wont let me, apparently not enough comments or something

Comment: @user2269083 put your code here http://liveworkspace.org/ and send me the link in comments

Comment: @user2269083 OK. try to go through the code yourself, you will find out. assuming m = 10, RootM becomes(sqrt(10)+1)^2 = 16, so  RootN1 4. so when you try to map 10 chars 1d array to 2d char matrix with 16 chars, what do you expect to see?  in this case, the mapping is not 2*i +j anymore since number of rows is 4, not 2. see my updated post in a minute.

Comment: do you know any other chat platforms? the liveworkspace website is confusing

Comment: so N=the number of rows, in others words if i have if i have 10 letters it would read every 4th letter i.e 1st letter, 5th letter, 9th, 2nd, 6th, 10th, 3rd, 7th, 4th and 8th ...right?

Comment: yeah exactly i get a out of bounds error because if a have a 4*4 grid and only 10 letters what happens then? The loop doesnt continue hence error..what do i do now?

Answer (score 0):

What you do in that cascaded for loop is following:

```
box[0] = "abcd";
box[0] = "abcd";
box[0] = "abcd";
box[1] = "abcd";
box[1] = "abcd";
box[0] = "abcd";
...
```

I don't exactly know how you are trying to fill that 2d-array, but I guess you will have to do something similar to `box[i][j] = letters[2*i+j]`.